# Set segments on video track

Tags: wpf, slider

I'm trying to make a player that user can click on the slider and mark a segment. The segment should be appear at different color. Also, there should be tiny button on both sides of segment, so the user can click on them to cancel/change it's position.

Can you recommend me how to achieve this targets ?
How to place the tiny buttons so they stay in their position when user resize the player(and the slider with it)?